# javafx- unable to add items to Listview

Tags: javafx

there is my fxml file:

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="anch" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <ListView fx:id="list" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="393.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and controllerfile :

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> list;

@FXML
private AnchorPane anch;

ObservableList<String> li = FXCollections.observableArrayList("red","blue","yellow");

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    list.setItems(li);

}
```

When I run the program the program, it only shows the empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Miss `fx:controller` in FXML

Ex:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="380.0" prefWidth="387.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="PackageName.ControllerFileName">
```

[here's document from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers)

Comment: @manpreetsinghwadhoun If a answer worked for you and there doesn't seem to be an issue with quality or something like that, consider accepting the answer.